# Limitar tempo de resposta de uma função

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz um script em **python 3** que realiza testes de velocidade na minha internet a cada 60 segundos e escreve esses resultados em um arquivo *.txt*.

Dentro deste script eu tenho uma função chamada *get_results* que é a função responsável por realizar o teste de velocidade da internet e retornar um *dict* com os resultados obtidos.
Porém caso durante o teste de velocidade a minha conexão venha a cair o teste de velocidade não finaliza e meu programa fica travando, me obrigando a manualmente interrompê-lo.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é estipular um tempo limite para o retorno desta função *get_results* e se no tempo estipulado ela não me retornasse nada ela seria interrompida e o script continuaria com  o fluxo normal de esperar mais 60 segundos para realizar o novo teste.

[Código
 Fonte no GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/CleysonPH/f283749e2ad8d31fc8cdfa23b6695caf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: Posta o código, pelo menos os da função.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código fonte.